# How to build a dictionary in Python based on my list?

Tags: python

I have a simple list

```
a = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

and I am trying to build something similar to this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "foo",
        "value": "one"
    },
    {
        "key": "foo",
        "value": "two"
    },
    {
        "key": "foo",
        "value": "three"
    }
]
```

What's the easiest way to achieve it?

Just for the record, here is what I was trying to do:
b = [item.update({"key":"foo"}) for item in a]
but I was stuck with an error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'"

Comment: `[{'key': 'foo', 'value': value} for value in a]`

Comment: you realize that your dictionaries have a key called `"key"` and a key called `"value"` instead of a single `key:value` pair right?

Comment: What do you gain by putting your list in this format? All the other data is redundant. If I had the data structure you're shooting for, I would probably simplify it and extract out exactly what you have as your list `a`.

Comment: Yes, that was intentional.

Comment: I am building a payload that requires that format for an API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple comprehension

```
[{"key": "foo", "value": v} for v in ["one", "two", "three"]]
```

But you probably want something more like

```
[{"foo": v} for v in ["one", "two", "three"]]
```

which gives you

```
In [11]: [{"foo": v} for v in ["one", "two", "three"]]
Out[11]: [{'foo': 'one'}, {'foo': 'two'}, {'foo': 'three'}]
```